# Run 2 infinite loops parallel in a script, and kill when script stops

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, ksh

I am writing a script in which I want to run multiple infinite loops in parallel.

I tried running then in background which works, But I want the loops to be killed when the script stops.

scripts example :

```
#### SYNC CALL ####
while true            :: Loop 1 ::
do
sync_stat
sleep $SYNC_TIME 
done &

#### TABLESPACE CALL ####  :: Loop 2 ::
while true
do
tablespace_stat
sleep $TABLESPACE_TIME 
done &
```

Want to run script containing Loop1 and Loop2 , such that these loops run simultaneously, in background or foreground , and when script stops the loops should stop.

Answer (score 0):

You can kill all children of the current with:

```
pkill -P $$
```

Try tag this to end of your script.

Answer (score 0):

you have a two options

**Option1**: It is better to put use some variable with while & change its value in while lopp statement.

```
while true
do
x=`sync_stat`
if [ <condition on $x variable> ];
then
break;
fi
sleep $SYNC_TIME 
done &
```

**Option2**: just run the script using bash command `bash <script name>` & use `pkill bash` to kill the running script whenever you want.